# MYSQL: Repeated query into one query, Select column1 if string is contained in column2 but not in column3

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query that I have to execute multiple times at once with different user id's. The query takes a long time, 7-8 seconds each time.  I've been trying to figure out a way to combine the queries, do everything at once. I can't seem to figure anything out besides unions, which doesn't help with the query time.

*user id: 3928946874*

```
SELECT
  id_follows
FROM
  follows
WHERE LOCATE('3928946874', followers)
  AND NOT LOCATE('3928946874', unfollowers)
LIMIT 1
```

**Sample Table Data:**

```
id_follows  followers                                    unfollowers  
----------  -------------------------------------------  -------------
1741189299  @603130974@4071609847@3928946874             @603130974   
  41075294  @603130974@4056752304@3928946874                          
2101481390  @603130974@4055755876@3928946874             @603130974   
  25799418  @603130974@4026505111@3928946874             @4026505111   
 231677952  @603130974@3928946874                        @603130974   
 367919322  @603130974@3928946874@4053729792                
1376365648  @603130974@3928946874@4049702500             @603130974
```

If I can do multiple (50ish) user id's at once, I need a way to be able to tell which `id_follows` were selected from which user id

Pretty sure it can't be done efficiently, but though I would try here anyways.

**

### EDIT

**

Well I changed my query a little bit to:

```
SELECT
  id_follows
FROM
  follows
WHERE MATCH(followers) AGAINST('3928946874')
  AND NOT MATCH(unfollowers) AGAINST('3928946874')
LIMIT 1
```

And made `followers` and `unfollowers` FULLTEXT indexes, this sped my query times from 7-8 seconds to 0.3 seconds!!

*Still looking for a way to combine multiple of these queries into one so I don't have to loop through making tons of queries.*

Comment: Gosh.  If you want a database to work well, you should use a proper data model.  In your case, this means have a table with one row per `id` and one per `follower`.  Fix the data model, fix the performance problem.

Comment: to me you may need to restructure your table. use those id as numbers, not text strings. operation on numbers is quicker than on strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff have  about 10 million rows as it is. A row per follower/unfollower puts me over 50 million and makes thing real slow as I have to have another table and do joins to get relevant info.

Comment: @jpizzle . . . And your point is?  50,000,000 is not outrageously large.

Comment: @GordonLinoff select queries were three times as long when I tested the db relational-ly

Comment: @jpizzle . . . You probably just don't know how to optimize the database to run the queries.  Plus, you can't optimize the query in this question, so you would have to weight that into the assessment as well.

Comment: >You probably just don't know how to optimize the database to run the queries.

Apparently